I'm not able to remove the arrow in python turtle while trying draw a circle of flowers
I have encountered an issue with the turtle graphics code. Despite trying various methods to hide the turtle, such as using bob.hideturtle() at different points in the code, the arrow remains visible. Additionally, I attempted to move the arrow to an off-screen location, but this approach did not resolve the problem.
I suspect there may be a small error somewhere in the code that is causing this issue. Could you please help me identify and fix the problem?
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
scr = turtle.getscreen()
scr.bgcolor("#85B14E")
bob.speed(0)  
bob.color("yellow")
turtle.tracer(0)  
turtle.hideturtle() 
def flower():
    for i in range(21):
        bob.forward(20)
        bob.left(163)

def flowers():
    for i in range(49):
        bob.penup()
        bob.goto(0, 0) 
        bob.forward(150)
        bob.pendown()
        flower()
        bob.penup()
        bob.goto(0, 0) 
        bob.left(8)
flowers()
turtle.hideturtle()  
turtle.update()    
bob.goto(1000,10000)
turtle.done()

Here is the link to the image for reference:


I know absolutely nothing about this. But I can't help but notice you made a turtle called "bob", and you did not hide bob.

i tried that but didn't work. Actually @ggorlen answered my question if u want to check

Your first problem is import turtle, which tempts you to call turtle. functions on the top-level module. turtle. functions like .getscreen() and .hideturtle(), auto-instantate a default turtle, different than bob or any others you manually created. This is a common source of bugs in turtle graphics programs (see below).
So always use the following import: from turtle import Screen, Turtle. This way, you're forced to instantiate a turtle and there's no way to access the auto-instantiated turtle. namespace.
Here's a rewrite:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


def draw_flower(t: Turtle):
    for _ in range(21):
        t.forward(20)
        t.left(163)


def draw_flowers(t: Turtle):
    for _ in range(49):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0, 0)
        t.forward(150)
        t.pendown()
        draw_flower(t)
        t.penup()
        t.goto(0, 0)
        t.left(8)


bob = Turtle()
scr = Screen()
scr.bgcolor("#85B14E")
scr.tracer(0)
bob.color("yellow")
bob.hideturtle()
draw_flowers(bob)
scr.update()
scr.exitonclick()

Notes:

Pass parameters into functions rather than relying on magic global variables. Functions should be self-contained to avoid bugs and to make debugging easier when an issue does arise.
Function names should only be nouns when they're getters (i.e., they return the noun). Otherwise, make them verbs. Name them what the function does.
Try to avoid hardcoded values--it's OK here, but draw_flowers is pretty rigid. Using relative movements (avoid goto) and dynamically-computed numbers will make it easier to extend and reuse in the future.
bob.goto(1000,10000) is called after turtle.update(), so its result is never reflected on the screen. Make sure movements happen before calling .update().

Related questions about "ghost turtles":

Why is there a second Turtle?
Why is there a little arrow in the middle of the screen?
Little black square in center of screen after each restart in turtle graphics pong game
Third Clone Of The Turtle


As the turtle module is mainly used for teaching python, I think it might be worth noting that turtle.hideturtle vs turtle.Turtle.hideturtle is a fairly common idiom in python. It's used when creating more than one instance of a class is considered a rare or specialised use case. eg. compare random.randint with random.Random.randint.

@Dunes Good to know, but random is a much better-designed module and has way fewer footguns than turtle, especially for beginners. I can't think of any use case where mixing instance mode and functional mode in turtle is beneficial. In random, there are use cases for mixing and the behavior is sensible (as far as I know).

I imagine because turtle is used for teaching, the module level functions exist so beginners can do stuff with a turtle without having to first learn about classes and variables. To get started, all they really need to know is numbers and how to call a function.

I'm aware that that's why they made the feature--one line to instantiate a class and having to type t. over and over might be hard for those with poor typing skills--it's closer to the original Logo syntax. But that doesn't change the fact that it still leads to a ton of bugs and confusion. See the links I shared.

hideturtle() method should be on bob
You can do:
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
scr = bob.getscreen()

or
scr = Screen()

then try:
bob.hideturtle()

getscreen() is a turtle method, so when you call it with the module name turtle.getscreen() it applies to the default turtle.
It gets you the screen, but also instantiates the default turtle.

You need to call the hideturtle() method on your Turtle instance bob.
You need to change
turtle.hideturtle()

into
bob.hideturtle()

You claim to have tried it in your question but the actual code shows a different thing.

This achieves OP's result, but doesn't really avoid the fundamental problem. OP should not be mixing functional and instance interfaces. If they stuck to instance mode all the way through and fixed their import, they'll never encounter any form of this bug going forward.
